# How to get Button position in visible Scrollview?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview

I have many controls in the `UIScrollView` including few buttons. For an example I have a button at position `(300,200`) from where I am popping `UIPopOverController` to do required tasks but when I scroll scrollview is scrolled, `popover` still pops up from the location `(300,200)` which is wrong! Is there anyway to get button position in visible scroll view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I get the exact position of button while knowing it's initial position in `UIScrollView`. I just need to subtract current scrollview offset from button's Y coordinate! For me X coordinate doesn't change - as no horizontal scrolling supported.

```
 CGPoint point = CGPointMake(self.button.frame.origin.x, 
                 self.button.frame.origin.y - self.scrollView.contentOffset.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it pops ut at the wrong position because it is not added at the UIScrollView, but at its superview. Try to check in the views hierarchy the position of the button. Another thing you can do to retrieve the button position is to go inside the view hierarchy and extract the arrays of subviews, and check the position of the button here.
Take a look at this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW17

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIView` `convertRect:toView:` or `convertRect:fromView:` method.